# Run two commands during git bisect run

Tags: git, bisect

I would essentially like to do `git bisect run 'bundle && bundle exec cucumber'`.

I want to do this on the commandline - I don't want to write a shell script.

Comment: My question has been answered; however, I should note that running these commands this way with `git bisect` doesn't seem to work (some kind of SEG fault), so I still have to run them 'manually'.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
git bisect run sh -c 'bundle && bundle exec cucumber'
```